# Formatting a string to date

Tags: date, oracle-sqldeveloper, to-date

I have a date: 'Fri Jul 24 13:11:04 CEST 2015'. How can I convert this string to a date?
Ultimately I would like to do something like that:

```
to_char('Fri Jul 24 13:11:04 CEST 2015', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
```

I tried approaches but all failed so far with this error:

```
ORA-01858:  -  "a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected"
*Cause:    The input data to be converted using a date format model was
           incorrect.  The input data did not contain a number where a number was
           required by the format model.
*Action:   Fix the input data or the date format model to make sure the
           elements match in number and type.  Then retry the operation.
```

Would it even be possible for me to do what I want here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `to_date`:

```
to_date('Fri Jul 24 13:11:04 CEST 2015', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
```

http://ss64.com/ora/syntax-to_date.html

`to_char` is expecting numbers only

http://ss64.com/ora/syntax-to_char.html